# Destroy Datacontext on leaving page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I set `DataContext` in `Page.xaml.cs`

```
DataContext = new PageViewModel();
```

In `PageViewModel` I create Data Manager, which subscribes to different event, load data, generate event for ViewModel.

But, when I leave page my ViewModel and DataManager objects continue to live and when I go to this page again, new ViewModel and DataManager created, now there are two object load same data etc.
How to avoid this leak?

Comment: When I use parameterized ViewModel eg `new SomeObjectViewModel(int objectId)` what solution will be cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

Have a cleanup method in your VM to unsubscribe from all the events and cleanup any other resources and then invoke than method when navigating away from the Page. Also, set the DataContext to null when navigating away.

Or, use a single instance of that ViewModel for the DataContext so it doesn't get recreated. See how MVVM Light can do it easily for you with a ViewModelLocator, but you can just as easily do it yourself without any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to igrali's answer. you can implement the singleton instance of the Viewmodel (which in turn contains the datamanager). So even clean-up wont be necessary because you would have a single viewmodel.

```
    public class MyViewModel
    {
         private static MyViewModel instance;

         private MyViewModel() {}

         public static MyViewModel Instance
         {
            get 
            {
             if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new MyViewModel();
                }
             return instance;
            }
          }
      }
```

So, instead of called a new Viewmodel() everytime, you can just call the MyViewModel.instance() which will create only if it is necessary. You can further refer the net for thread-safe singleton implementation to handle scenarios where multiple calls are made to this class at the same time which is a possibility.

If your datamanger is independent of the viewmodel, you can implement the same singleton pattern for other classes also.